# Bluetooth baseadapter and listview in C#

Tags: c#, android, bluetooth

I have a simple program that would find a paired device, then try to access it.
I am getting an exception when executing the line:

> _listView.Adapter = lvadapter

The lvadapter is an object to a class that inherits from BaseAdapter

Here is my code.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
        txtView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);


        button.Click +=  (Object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            txtView.Append("Reading Serial Ports\r\n");
            try
            {
                BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
                _items = new List<BluetoothInfo>();
                if (adapter == null)
                   LogMsg("No Bluetooth adapter found");
                else if (!adapter.IsEnabled)
                    LogMsg("Bluetooth adapter is not enabled");
                else
                {
                    LogMsg("Bluetooth adapter found and enabled, looking for paired devices...");

                    // this was looking for the BlueSnap Bluetooth-Serial Adapter only
                    //BluetoothDevice device = (from bd in adapter.BondedDevices
                    //                          where bd.Name == "BlueSnapXP-A7CF"
                    //                          select bd).FirstOrDefault();

                    devices = (from bd in adapter.BondedDevices
                                                     select bd).ToList();
                    LogMsg("debug 2: number of paired devices found: " + devices.Count);
                    foreach (BluetoothDevice dev in devices)
                    {
                        LogMsg("debug 3. dev = " + dev.Name);
                        try
                        {
                            //DeviceName = dev.Name;
                            _items.Add(new BluetoothInfo() { DeviceName = dev.Name });
                            LogMsg("debug 4");
                        }
                        catch { LogMsg("exception on device " + dev.Name); }
                    }

                    BTListViewAdapter lvadapter = new BTListViewAdapter(this, _items);

                    if (_items.Count > 0 && lvadapter != null)
                    {
                        LogMsg("setting listview adapter");
                        _listView.Adapter = lvadapter;
                        LogMsg("debug 8. set listview event");
                        _listView.ItemClick += BTListView_ItemClick;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (_items.Count == 0)
                            LogMsg("Not paired items found");
                        else
                            LogMsg("listViewAdapter null");

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogMsg("Exception detected: " + ex.Message);
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Can u be more specific _I am getting an exception_?

Comment: BluetoothInfo is a class that has property DeviceName that stores the device name of the paired device.